# React JS - Higher Order Component, return function on mount

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, html5-video, higher-order-components

I am attempting to make custom controls for an HTML5 video player, using the reat-html5video HoC example:

```
import videoConnect from 'react-html5video';

const MyVideoPlayer = ({ video, videoEl, children, ...restProps }) => (
    <div>
        <video {...restProps}>
            { children }
        </video>
        <p>
            Here are the video properties for the above HTML5 video:
            { JSON.stringify(video) }
        </p>
        <a href="#" onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            // You can do what you like with the HTMLMediaElement DOM element also.
            videoEl.pause();
        }}>
            Pause video
        </a>
    </div>
);

export default videoConnect(MyVideoPlayer)
```

It seems fairly simple to add functionality to a button via "onClick", as illustrated below:

```
  <button className={styles.rewindBTN} onClick ={() => {
        videoEl.currentTime -= 5;
        }
      } hidden={false} ></button>

      <button id="playPauseBTN" className={styles.playPauseBTN} onClick={() => {
        if (videoEl.paused) {
            videoEl.play()
            document.getElementById('playPauseBTN').style.backgroundImage = "url('./components/HoC/img/pause.png')";
          } else {
            videoEl.pause()
            document.getElementById('playPauseBTN').style.backgroundImage = "url('./components/HoC/img/play.png')";
            }
           }
         } hidden={false}></button>

      <button className={styles.replayBTN} onClick ={() => {
        videoEl.currentTime = 0;
        videoEl.play()
        }
      } hidden={true} ></button>
```

I am able to access the  props (i.e. 'currentTime' and 'duration') like this:

```
const updateTime = ( videoEl, currentTime ) => {
    let curMins = Math.floor(videoEl.currentTime / 60);
    let curSecs = Math.floor(videoEl.currentTime - curMins * 60);
    let durMins = Math.floor(videoEl.duration / 60);
    let durSecs = Math.floor(videoEl.duration - durMins * 60);
    if(curSecs < 10){ curSecs = "0"+curSecs; }
    if(durSecs < 10){ durSecs = "0"+durSecs; }
    if(curMins < 10){ curMins = curMins; }
    if(durMins < 10){ durMins = durMins; }
    document.getElementById('curTimeText').innerHTML = curMins+":"+curSecs;
    document.getElementById('durTimeText').innerHTML = durMins+":"+durSecs;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to fire the "updateTime()" function when the component mounts and update the time as the video is playing. The function does return currentTime/duration...I placed a call to the function inside the "playPauseBTN onClick" event and the info updates each time I click the playPauseBTN.

How do I get the function to display duration as soon as the component mounts and update the currentTime as the video plays?

I am new to the concept of Higher Order Components, so forgive me if this is an obvious blunder on my part.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

*** UPDATED CODE *** (wrapped the Video01Player component in a class)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Motion, spring } from 'react-motion';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import videoConnect from 'react-html5video';

import styles from '../html5Video.css';
import customNav from '../customNav.scss';

import Video01Labels from '../Video01Labels';
import Video01Captions from '../Video01Captions';

const overlayContainer = document.querySelector('.overlayContainer');
const progressBarFill = document.querySelector('.progressBarFill');
const playPauseBTN = document.querySelector('.playPauseBTN');
const curTimeText = document.querySelector(".curTimeText");
const durTimeText = document.querySelector(".durTimeText");
const videoEl  = document.getElementById('vid01');
const src = "./components/HoC/video/video01.mp4";

class Video01Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateTime = this.updateTime.bind(this);
    this.updateProgress = this.updateProgress.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.updateTime(Video01Player, videoEl)
     this.updateProgress(Video01Player, videoEl)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
     this.updateTime(Video01Player, videoEl)
     this.updateProgress(Video01Player, videoEl)
  }

  // Update Video Time
    updateProgress( Video01Player, videoEl, currentTime, duration ) {
     // Calculate current progress
     var value = (100 / videoEl.duration) * videoEl.currentTime;

     // Update the slider value
     document.getElementById('progressBarFill').style.width = value + '%';
    }

    updateTime( Video01Player, videoEl, currentTime, duration ) {
        let curMins = Math.floor(videoEl.currentTime / 60);
        let curSecs = Math.floor(videoEl.currentTime - curMins * 60);
        let durMins = Math.floor(videoEl.duration / 60);
        let durSecs = Math.floor(videoEl.duration - durMins * 60);
        if(curSecs < 10){ curSecs = "0"+curSecs; }
        if(durSecs < 10){ durSecs = "0"+durSecs; }
        if(curMins < 10){ curMins = curMins; }
        if(durMins < 10){ durMins = durMins; }
        document.getElementById('curTimeText').innerHTML = curMins+":"+curSecs;
        document.getElementById('durTimeText').innerHTML = durMins+":"+durSecs;
    }


  render() {

    const { Video01Player, videoEl, children, paused, duration, currentTime, ...restProps } = this.props

    return (

      <div className={styles.videoContainer}>
          <video className={styles.videoWrapper} id="vid01" src={src} type="video/mp4" { ...restProps } >
              { children }
          </video>

        <div className={styles.videoControlsWrapper}>

          <button className={styles.rewindBTN} onClick ={() => {
            videoEl.currentTime -= 5;
            }
          } hidden={false} ></button>

          <button id="playPauseBTN" className={styles.playPauseBTN} onClick={( currentTime, duration ) => {
            if (videoEl.paused) {
                videoEl.play()
                document.getElementById('playPauseBTN').style.backgroundImage = "url('./components/HoC/img/pause.png')";
                } else {
                videoEl.pause()
                document.getElementById('playPauseBTN').style.backgroundImage = "url('./components/HoC/img/play.png')";
                }
               }
             } hidden={false}></button>

          <button className={styles.replayBTN} onClick ={() => {
            videoEl.currentTime = 0;
            videoEl.play()
            }
          } hidden={true} ></button>

          <div className={styles.progressBar}>
            <div id="progressBarFill" className={styles.progressBarFill}></div>
          </div>

          <button className={styles.forwardBTN} onClick={() => {
            videoEl.currentTime += 5;
            }
          }></button>

          <div className={styles.timeWrapper}>
            <span id="curTimeText" className={styles.curTimeText}>00:00</span> / <span id="durTimeText" className={styles.durTimeText}>00:00</span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className={styles.overlayContainer} data-tid="container">
          <Video01Labels />
          <Video01Captions />
        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default videoConnect(Video01Player);
```

Comment: make MyVideoPlayer a class component and call updateTime on componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for the quick response. I wrapped the Player in a class, but I am receiving the following error: "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Comment: @RaviTeja I figured out the above error...had to remove the arrow function from the original Player component. Now I need to understand how to properly export the "videoEl" object and it's props to the page that contains this component. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, this has been bugging  me for days. I need a break...I'm going to the beach : )

Comment: @Ravi I wrapped the player in a class component and everything still works as expected with my onClick events, but when I call the "updateTime" function from "componentDidMount" and "componentWillReceiveProps" i receive the following error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTime' of undefined" I have a feeling that I am missing something very trivial, but I am not completely familiar with the ES6/JSX syntax. I posted my update code in my original question...any suggestions?

Comment: May I know why are you passing the component as an argument? Also, change the signature of update functions to accept props. Like

updateTime(props) {
    const { videoEl } = props;
}

Comment: @Ravi I am still learning about Higher Order Components, but from what I understand so far...from this example: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5video), the HoC example use "MyVideoPlayer" as an argument for "videoConnect". There is not much documentation on the react-html5video module...I am having difficulty understanding the concept of the HoC.

Comment: can you create a codepen or code sandbox with the code? I will be able to help.